# python: differences between init method and in-class declare?

Tags: python

is there any difference between these two method?
option1 :

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 123
        self.y = 345
```

option2 :

```
class a(object):
        x = 123
        y = 345
```

is there any difference between these two options? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of the first method (instance level variables):

```
instance0 = a()
instance1 = b()

instance0.x = 5
print instance1.x # prints 123

print a.x  # undefined variable - x is not defined
```

An example of the second method (class level variables):

```
instance0 = a()
instance1 = b()

instance0.x = 5
print instance1.x # prints 5

print a.x  # prints 5
```

The second method, the variables are assigned at the class level meaning changing this value propagates to all instances of that class. You can also access the variables without an instance of the class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the first case each object of class a has its own copy of x and y, in the second case all objects of class a share them.

By the way, if your starting out with Python, use a capital for the first character of your class names, e.g. MyClass. People are used to that and it will help you understand your own programs once they get bigger.